# Kernel module that uses another USB ethernet module

Tags: linux-device-driver

I have a micro-controller (MCU) and a micro-processor (MPU) connected via an ethernet link.

**Micro-controller**

- Bare metal
- Native Ethernet MAC/PHY

**Micro-processor**

- Linux
- USB to Ethernet device

Connectivity

```
MCU <--eth--> ETH2USB <--usb--> MPU
```

The MCU has RS485 and CAN connections, and I would like to write a driver that would be loaded by the MPU that would create a socketCAN interface, a serial driver (and GPIO/SPI etc.) The exchange protocol has a custom header (i.e., to determine type, sequence count etc.) followed by the payload.

I have been doing some research but I cannot really see the recommended way to do this. I see two options

1. Modify the USB2ETH driver in Linux, and when it is loaded it creates the socketCAN and serial interfaces.
2. Write a new driver that leverages the eth0 interface already created to send/receive ethernet data (kind of like a tap interface).

I am seeking guidance on the recommended approach for socketCAN/serial to Ethernet communication. I would also like to know if there is any relevant online documentation that would help me look into this further. Additionally, I would like to know if the communications should be done over IP or Ethernet (i.e., should I add an IP address or use raw Ethernet frames).

My main question is how to capture a message sent to socketCAN/serial, add the exchange header, and then send it out the Ethernet interface (for both approaches mentioned above) from within another Kernel driver (and for information in the opposite direction)

Comment: If you don't need fragmentation or routing, then you can just use raw Ethernet packets with your own protocol. You will have to address by MAC. Don't mess with the existing USB2ETH which you know works. Never fight a war on multiple fronts.

Comment: Seems like alive project: https://github.com/m10k/canny.

Comment: @stark - number 2 then. Any documentation on how to send/receive raw ethernet packets from another driver to the NIC driver?